# How can websites where large photos are the primary focus make money?

Tags: google-adsense, images

I was reading:

http://www.bloggingspell.com/google-page-layout-algorithm/

and I find that the photos on the mobile version of my site seem to violate rule #2 and maybe rule #3 and #4, and definitely #5.

Going on with suggestion #5, they article recommends that I should have the photo below the fold, but the problem is that thousands of guests will be looking for that photo by scrolling down which is the reason why they arrived to the page in the first place. Currently I have the photo taking up nearly the entire above-the-fold space, and I'm making $0 RPM from adsense on that page.

How can I then make money on such pages without causing inconvenience to the guests? and scrolling will count as an inconvenience and many guests will not care to read text.

This is a sample page of what I refer to:

http://pictures.m.clubcatcher.com/ohso-nightclub/2012jun16/2

Also, placing text at the side will look rather funny and probably cause an inconvenience because people want to see the photos at the largest size possible.

But then is text beside the pictute the only way to pull this off?

Comment: Actually, from a spiders point of view, you can have the text first and the image second and the other way around for users using CSS. This should hopefully please the bots more. Understand that Adsense is focused around placing bids on a site. It is the content and search potential that bidders see. If there is none or little, bids may not come. Even more importantly, if the content does not attract users that would be interested in their product, then bids are lower if they happen at all. The "club" user base is easy to advertise to. You have to help the advertisers by making the connection.

Comment: Also take this guy with some salt. I do not think your site falls to far into this category. If you your site is image centric, then it would irritate users to scroll or hit the down button even a little bit per page over and over again.

Comment: Well I did make a change to it around 6 hours ago to add text to the side but that made the image smaller. Its the image that people want to see. Tonight ill put the text on the left and image on the right and see what happens

Comment: And I'm trying to avoid having the user to scroll to see the image. Google would love me if I had paragraphs of text before the image but that would irritate the users since that makes scrolling mandatory

Comment: Another experiment you can try is where the textual content is higher than the image in the HTML, but you turn it the other way around (or anyway around that makes sense) using CSS. That may help.

Comment: Way back in the day before Google recognized headers, footers, and sidebars, I had to restructure my HTML so that the content was higher in the HTML code than these elements, but used CSS to put it all straight in the browser for the user. This was because at the time, Google matched too easily against page elements that mattered far less.

Answer (score 1):

The main ideas of the cited article are:

- place no more then 3 ads above the fold
- place textual content above the fold
- don't place anything (like heavy weight images) above the fold, what could slow the page loading

What would i do?

- place well optimized thumbnail of the image above the fold
- locate the big image (good quality, big resolution == big weight) at external CDN
- load the big image only after user action, like `onClick`
- include in the head `<link rel="prefetch">` to the big image located on external CDN

Comment: But. users already select the thumbnail from the thumbnail of pictures to see the larger picture on site. Taking this advice would ask me to make user make additional clicks just to see the picture.

Comment: @Mike Correct! I think, the pathway (mobile device, mobile site version) should look like: user comes to page with some thumbnails. In the page's header are all large image versions prefetched. After choosing, which image user wants to see enlarged, he clicks on the thumbnail, and the `onClick` event loads the enlarged image. I suppose btw., that the enlarged image version isn't bigger, then the display of the user's mobile device. It isn't user friendly, if each image has an own page - it would be thin content.To avoid it you will be forced to write at least 200 characters long description.